# Comparing two files in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two files with similar content. for ex file1 is having file permission details of different foolders:

```
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/abc
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyzhrt/rth
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz/rhr/rthrh
-rw-rwxr--+  3 user1 hive       1462 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz/rhrhheh
-rw-rwxr--+  3 user1 hive          9 2017-01-31 16:55
```

File2 is having similar content.

I want to compare both files such that if folders in file1 are having same permission as folder with same name in file2 then print the complete line and then PASS or else False.

Comment: I am not comparing permissions of files directly. I am getting two files with content as written above. now I want to do compare first column of both files based on last column.

Comment: put the content of **File2** in your question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$ cat a.txt
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/abc
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyzhrt/rth
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz/rhr/rthrh
-rw-rwxr--+  3 user1 hive       1462 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz/rhrhheh

$ cat b.txt
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/abc
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz

$ sort a.txt b.txt |uniq -d
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/abc
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 hive          0 2017-01-31 16:55 /user/anc/xyz
```

## Update

Uniq -d prints the duplicate lines. Above simple method works if both files have identical lines.

In order to find files present in both files based on same folder name (column 8) and on same permissions you can do something like this:

```
sort -k8 a.txt b.txt |awk '{print $1,$8}' |uniq -d
```

`sort -k8` will sort both files using column 8 as sorting key (folder name)
`awk` will print field 1 (permissions) and field 8 (folder)
`uniq -d` will find the exact duplicate entries, meaning in this case identical permissions and folder name (formatted by awk)

You can then pull out the common lines from any of files with a kind of grep.

As a result , this works ok based on first and last column, even with multiple maches:

```
$ common=$(sort -k8 a.txt b.txt |awk '{print $1":"$8}' |uniq -d|cut -d':' -f2)
$ grep -F "$common" a.txt
```

Offcourse a variety of solutions with other tools like awk, etc is possible.

Comment: *I want to do compare first column of both files based on last column* he said

Answer (score 0):

**First of ALL**
print the first column and then the last that would be name of the file

`perl -a -nE 'print $F[0]," ", ((split(/\//,$_))[-1])'`

**output of this:**

```
drwxrwxr-x+ abc  
drwxrwxr-x+ xyz  
drwxrwxr-x+ rth  
drwxrwxr-x+ rthrh  
-rw-rwxr--+ rhrhheh
```

---

you told me: *I am getting two files with content as written above. now I want to do compare first column of both files based on last column*  **and** *File2 is having similar content.*

So I assumed that the only different in your both files are in **the permission** of them.
okay now you can easily **store** the output of your file into difference file such as: **file_1** and **file_1** and then **compare** them by using `diff` on command-line. that's it.

```
$ cat file_1  
drwxrwxr-x+ abc  
drwxrwxr-x+ xyz  
drwxrwxr-x+ rth  
drwxrwxr-x+ rthrh  
-rw-rwxr--+ rhrhheh  

$ cat 2  
drwxrwxr-x+ abc  
drwxrwxr-x+ xyz  
drwxrwxr-x+ rth  
drwxrwxr--+ rthrh  
-rw-rwxr--+ rhrhheh  

$ diff file_1 file_2
4c4  
< drwxrwxr-x+ rthrh  
---  
> drwxrwxr--+ rthrh
```